# SQL Server Geography (Spartial) finding gaps between instances

Tags: sql, sql-server, geography

I have not found a way to spot gaps between geographic instances and I hope you guys can help me with this. The aim would be to find the "gap-polygon". I'm working on the SQL-Server 2012.

Here is an easy example:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp1
(
    [ID] [int],
    [Geo] [geography] NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #temp1
VALUES (1,geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0.1 0, 0.1 0.1, 0 0.1,0 0))', 4326))

INSERT INTO #temp1
VALUES (2,geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((0.11 0.05, 0.15 0.05, 0.15 0.15, 0.11 0.15, 0.11 0.05 ))', 4326))

INSERT INTO #temp1
VALUES (3,geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0.1, 0.11 0.1, 0.11 0.15, 0 0.15, 0 0.1))', 4326))

INSERT INTO #temp1
VALUES (4,geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((0.1 0.05, 0.1 0, 0.15 0, 0.15 0.05, 0.1 0.05))', 4326))

SELECT * 
FROM #temp1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a 2012 (or later) instance handy, but this should work if you do:

```
select EnvelopeAggreate([Geo]).STDifference( UnionAggregate([Geo]) )
from #temp
```